# In Apache make subdirectory require basic authentication while parent directory is open to the public

Tags: apache, authentication

I want to make the contents of the directory `/srv/www/dssx` (mostly) public. The *sub-directory* `/srv/www/dssx/basic-auth` of `/srv/www/dssx` I want to protect with basic authentication. However, I cannot get it to work: all the configurations I have tried allow public access to the sub-directory without requiring basic auth. Here is my configuration:

```
# Running under Apache 2.4.38
DocumentRoot /srv/www/dssx

# Allow unrestricted access to all XML and PEM files.                                                                                                 
<Directory "/srv/www/dssx">
  Require all denied
  <FilesMatch "\.(pem|xml)$">
    Require all granted
  </FilesMatch>
</Directory>

# We require Basic Auth (username and password) for this sub-directory                                                            
<Directory "/srv/www/dssx/basic-auth">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "DSSX Restricted Content"
  AuthBasicProvider file
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dssx-restricted-auth
  Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

With the above, the URL `https://example.com/basic-auth/test.xml` is served without requiring basic authentication, whereas I want that URL to require basic authentication.

Comment: Any reason you are doing this in Apache conf files rather than creating a .htaccess file in the directory?

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that I needed to put a matching `FilesMatch` element in the subdirectory configuration section:

```
# We require Basic Auth (username and password) for this sub-directory                                                            
<Directory "/srv/www/dssx/basic-auth">
  <FilesMatch "\.(pem|xml)$">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "DSSX Restricted Content"
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dssx-restricted-auth
    Require valid-user
  </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```